# Android SDK. Self-sign app for release

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

PURPOSE OF QUESTION: Where do I get the "release.keystore"?

I am ready to package/export my app to .apk

I use Google maps so I can not longer use my debug key.

Now, I must self-sign my app and create a release key using a "release" keystore.

The only problem, how do I do this?

I here: https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup , ready to insert my new key, here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html , ready on different links, and doing Google searches.

Where is this release keystore? How do I self-sign my app? It will only be available from my website, not from the android market.

I also need to generate a release key for Google.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is this release keystore?

Wherever you created it, when you [followed the instructions in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

> How do I self-sign my app?

Using `jarsigner` or Eclipse, as is indicated [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

Comment: I recommend signing through Eclipse.  It's way easier.

Comment: @Sparky Maybe easier, but it's worth the effort to setup your Ant/Maven build to do the release signing so you can have your continuous integration rig handle it.